# android- performing crop image is not working properly

Tags: android, android-camera, android-gallery, android-camera-intent

I'm working with android crop image , this is my code for cropping image :

```
private void performCrop() {
    try {
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        //indicate image type and Uri
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
        //set crop properties
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        //indicate aspect of desired crop
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        //indicate output X and Y
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 500);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 500);
        //retrieve data on return
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        //display an error message
        String errorMessage = "err";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

I have tested this code on android 4.2 , 4.3 and the was no problem , but on android 5,6 , it's returning null pointer exception and I don't know why .

what is wrong with this code ? how can I make it compatible with all version of android ?

Comment: Make sure you applied permission model for Android 6

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use according to Build SDK 
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    performCrop(fileUri);
                } else {
                    performCropImage(fileUri);
                }
// code for device below 5 
private boolean performCropImage(Uri mFinalImageUri) {
        Uri mCropImagedUri;
        try {
            if (mFinalImageUri != null) {
                //call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not support it)
                Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
                //indicate image type and Uri
                cropIntent.setDataAndType(mFinalImageUri, "image/*");
                //set crop properties
                cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                //indicate aspect of desired crop
                cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
                cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
                cropIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
                // cropIntent.p
                //indicate output X and Y
                cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
                cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
                //retrieve data on return
                cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", false);

                File f = createNewFile("CROP_");
                try {
                    f.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Log.e("io", ex.getMessage());
                }

                mCropImagedUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
                cropIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCropImagedUri);
                //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
                startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
                return true;
            }
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            //display an error message
            String errorMessage = getString(R.string.crop_not_supported);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
// code for 5 or 6  
 private void performCrop(Uri picUri) {
        try {

            Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            // indicate image type and Uri
            cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
            // set crop properties
            cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            // indicate aspect of desired crop
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            // indicate output X and Y
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
            // retrieve data on return
            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
            startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
        }
        // respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            // display an error message
            String errorMessage = getString(R.string.crop_not_supported);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }

On ActivityResult put this code 

Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                    try {
                        Bitmap selectedBitmap;
                        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                            selectedBitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
                        } else {
                            selectedBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);

                        }


// I hope you this code help you
```